# Selectable table row cannot sent id value to PHP via jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

Hello friends this is my first question.I'm a new in jquery+ajax. I want to selectable my table row and can be delete any row when choose on it + click delete button. Now i can't traverse the DOM and send id of any row to PHP file.

Now I can :

1. Selectable table row.
2. Show id that selected on alert box.
3. Delete any row when select + click delete button.

But I can't :

1. Send id of any row on selected to php file (Thay show message "undefined").
2. Delete them out to database.

A question
 - why alert box show 2,3,4,... times  when I choose row + click delete button 2,3,4,.. times???  I want to show one time.

What's wrong I need to do???

Sorry for my bad English.

Please help me...Thanks so much.

---

**jQuery code :**

```
$('#table2').selectable({
    filter:'tbody tr',
    stop: function(event, ui){
    $('#delete2').click(function(){
        var choose_data2 = $('#table2').find("tr.ui-selected").attr("id"); //--var for test--
        $('#table2').find("tr.ui-selected").remove('tr');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/dmht/tabs2_delete.php',
            type:'post',
            data:'choose_data2='+$('#table2').find("tr.ui-selected").attr("id"),
            cache: false,
            success :function(data){
                  alert(data);//---****---
            }
        });
    });
});
```

****   - if code : "*alert(data);*"  -->  When i click delete button,it will show message "undefined"

- if code  : "*alert(choose_data2);*" it will show "20/1/2013" that's my needs data return.

**PHP code (tabs2_delete.php):**

```
<?
include ("connect.php");
$q="DELETE FROM tabs2 WHERE HN = '".$_POST["choose_data2"]."'";
mysql_query($q);
echo $_POST["choose_data2"];
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

**This is example HTML code :**

```
<table id="table2">
 <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
</tr>

<tbody>
   <tr id="20/7/2014">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>D</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" name="delete2" id="delete2" value="Delete"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OH I already got it by my try !!!

This is my change a few code :

```
var choose_data2 = $('#table2').find(".ui-selected td:first-child").text();  //<---- This changed code ----
$('#table2').find("tr.ui-selected").remove('tr');

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/dmht/tabs2_delete.php',
    type:'post',
    data:'choose_data2='+choose_data2, //<------ This changed code -----
    cache: false,
    success :function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Thanks for viewed !!